# Term for people who feel they have some disorder when they read about it

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term for people who, when they read symptoms of some psychological disorder, start feeling that they have it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can think of [hypochondriasis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypochondriasis), although the term is not limited to reading about a disease nor is limited to psychological disorders (but any general illness). The word for a person who suffers from hypochondriasis is *hypochondriac*.

[Somatization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatization) may also apply in certain cases.

Comment: I think the topic is more related to the nature of suggestibility, and hypochondriacs believe they have good reason (if they just make it up, or decide to apply it because of some remote knowledge, then it becomes a different disorder like Münchausen, for instance.) Though, I'm not saying _they_ are not suggestible, mind you.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: point taken, however I am not aware of a specific condition related to reading (and not, say, hearing or seeing a picture) of a disease.

Comment: Well, to emphasise my point a little: the data source is irrelevant, the suggestibility is.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment, Hypochondriacs 'become unduly alarmed about any physical symptoms they detect, no matter how minor the symptom may be.' This fits perfectly to what OP seeks - even reading about symptoms will make a hypochondriac anxious. Nico, I prefer the term [hypochondria](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hypochondriasis%2Chypochondria%2Chealth+anxiety%2Chealth+phobia&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) although it seems to decline in use, but you still might want to mention it in the answer. Another interesting term is cyberchondria.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia defines [Medical student's disease](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_students%27_disease) as a specific form of hypochondriasis triggered by studying different diseases.

Answer (score 1):

They are experiencing a "phantom illness."